# Finding rotation and reflection in Galois Group D4

Tags: galois-theory

The Galoisgroup of $g(x)=x^4+14x^2+28\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the dihedral group $D_4$ of order 8. Usually one can now write down the square (with the vertices being the roots) so that the rotation and reflection can be obtained immediately by looking at the square. But since all 4 roots $\pm\alpha=\pm\sqrt{-7+\sqrt{21}}$ and $\pm\beta=\pm\sqrt{-7-\sqrt{21}}$ are complex, the reflection cannot be the complex conjugation. My guess is that the rotation is $r:\ \alpha\mapsto\beta\mapsto-\alpha\mapsto-\beta$, so the reflection must be $s:\ \beta\mapsto-\beta$, however, I am not sure how to verify those assumptions.

Edit: The splitting field should be $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, right?

Comment: What do you mean by **the** reflection? As a group of symmetries of a square $D_4$ has four reflections. Anyway, complex conjugation clearly maps $\pm\alpha\mapsto \mp\alpha,\pm\beta\mapsto\mp\beta$.

Comment: The reflection that generates the group together with the rotation ($D_4=\langle r,s\mid r^4, s^2,srs=r^{-1}\rangle$).

Comment: Any of the four reflections can serve in the role of $s$. They all satisfy the same relation with the rotation $r$.

Comment: Then let's say $r=(1234), s=(24)$.

Comment: Ok :-) You want an automorphism that has two of the roots as fixed points. There are still two choices, but I had my fun, so let's get serious. Yes, your suggested $s$ should be there as the only non-trivial automorphism of the subgroup $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)/\Bbb{Q}(\alpha))$. The automorphism $s':\alpha\mapsto-\alpha, \beta\mapsto\beta$ is the only non-trivial automorphism of another subgroup $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)/\Bbb{Q}(\beta))$. I need to spend a while thinking about the 4-cycles...

Comment: Yes, it is clear how the complex conjugation acts on the roots, but I am not able to retrieve the corresponding fixed field.

Comment: I suppose you'll rather have $(1\,2)(3\,4)$ (if we agree that $1=\alpha, 2=-\alpha, 3=\beta, 4=-\beta$). So to see the $D_4$ as "the" action of $D_4$ on a square, try $\alpha+(-\alpha)$, $-\alpha+\beta$, $\beta+(-\beta)$, $-\beta+\alpha$, perhaps.

Comment: @Hagen All the four zeros are on the imaginary axis, so I don't think we can "visualize" a square this time?

Comment: But $\alpha\beta=2\sqrt{7}$ and $\gamma:=\alpha^2-\beta^2=2\sqrt{21}$ generate the real subfield (= the fixed field of the complex conjugation). The fixed field of the rotation should thus be one of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$ with $n\in\{3,7,21\}$. I should stop and think rather than keep typing :-(

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},\sqrt{21})$ as the fixed field of the complex conjugation looks good!

Comment: Before we now invest too much time into computing the fixed field of the rotation. Is my given r the rotation at all? I feel dumb but I'm not quite able to proof that it's a field automorphism.

Comment: This time complex conjugation might be the 180 degree rotation?

Comment: I'm fairly sure your rotation is correct. Consider the following. Clearly $r$ is determined from knowing $r(\alpha)$ and $r(\beta)$. If $r(\alpha)=\pm\alpha$ then $r$ has order two. Therefore $r(\alpha)=\pm\beta$. Because we can always replace $r$ with $r^{-1}$ it doesn't matter which we choose. So let's pick $r(\alpha)=\beta$. Then $r(-\alpha)=-\beta$, so we must have $r(\beta)=\pm\alpha$. The plus sign, again, gives an automorphism of order two. Your choice remains.

Comment: Neither $\alpha\beta$ nor $\alpha^2-\beta^2$ is fixed under $r$, so it looks like the fixed field of $r$ would be $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3)=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha\beta(\alpha^2-\beta^2))$.